# Removing and Replacing Specific String Index using Python

Tags: python, list

Not sure where I'm going wrong here. I'm trying to append a string at a specific index. I can't use list methods except for append or string methods. I can only use the range built in function as well.

Here is my code:

```py
str1 = ['f','i','r','e']

def var1(list):
    count = 0
    for char in list:
        count += 1
    return count

def var2(list, remove):
    var3 = var1(list)
    new_list = []
    for e in list:
        if remove > var3:
            new_list.append(e)
        elif remove_position < var3:
            new_list.append(e)
    return new_list
```

Output should be `['i','r','e']`

Comment: It look like you are trying to *remove* an element from a list, not append (insert is the word) one

Comment: Can you please indent the code. I am having a hard time finding out where you func definition ends and main section starts.

Comment: In `var3` you have the returned value `var1(list)` which is the constant length of `list`. And in `remove` you have the constant position the caller sent. So the condition `if remove > var3` is always `True` or always `False`, and has nothing to do with `e`. BTW: avoid using `python` keywords (such as `list` or the function `remove`) as names for your variables. Use `myList` instead for example.

Comment: If you can use enumerate and generate another list do: `def rm(lst, p):
  return [v for i,v in enumerate(lst) if i != p]` then try
`print(rm(lstinput, 0))`

Comment: I'm not allowed to use the insert method. Sorry, probably should have been more clear by the index number given to me (forgot to the include) is dependent on the length of the string as to which element should be removed. I was given -1 so the output should be ['i','r','e']